# Apply templates when new file created

Tags: buffers, autocmd, plugin-nerdtree

I have a file template which is rendered with replacing some stubs when new file created:

```
augroup templates
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufNewFile *.java $r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.java|call s:SetupJavaClass()

  fun! s:SetupJavaClass()
    exe "%s/__CLASS_NAME__/" . expand('%:t:r')
  endfun
augroup END
```

it's working fine, but only if I create new file with new buffer, e.g. `vim Foo.java` works, but when I create new file from NerdTree, new file is opening in current buffer and my templates and vim doesn't call my autocommands. How can I fix it? Is it possible to create autocommand to be executed on every new file, doesn't matter it was opened in new buffer or not, or maybe I should use ftplugin for that?

Comment: How do you create a new file from NerdTree? I don't have much experience with NerdTree, and I only saw commands to open existing files.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer I'm opening menu with `m`, then `a` to add new file, then I type filename, it creates a file which I'm opening in current buffet with `o` key.

Comment: The `(a)dd a childnode` menu item will ultimately result in a call to `writefile([], a:fullpath)` inside `nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim`. I don't think there is an autocommand that is triggered by `writefile()`. You might want to ask the maintainer of NerdTree if he/she could provide a hook for reading a template file.

Comment: @JürgenKrämer thanks, submitted a ticket: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested `@PhilRunninger` in Github [ticket](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/1010#issuecomment-507104724), I can use `BufRead` autocommand and apply templates if file size is zero:

```
autocmd BufRead *.java if getfsize(expand('%'))==0|$r ~/.vim/templates/skeleton.java|call s:SetupJavaClass()|endif
```

it's working fine.